# get the wanted objects from the array of objects

Tags: javascript

This is my first question in stackoverflow, So any kind of help is appreciated.

I have an array like this

```
var products = [{status:'available', ...},{status:'none', ...},{status:'available', ...},{status:'', ...},{status:'none', ...}]
```

how can I get an array that contains only  `products[i].status = 'available'` .

I already did this with **for loop** but isn't there a better method? My code is practically full of loops now & it's not easy to read.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: use `filter()` function, `var res = products.filter(v => v.status == 'available')`

Comment: Here is the documentation for`filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using arrow functions (ES6) is a shortest one

```
products.filter(product => product.status == 'available')
```

Will return an appropriate array of products where statuses arr `"available"`

Comment: One line answer:)

Comment: just be careful though as not all browser support ES6

Answer (score 4):

Use `Array.filter` method

```
products.filter(function(product){
    return product.status == 'available'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var products = [{
  status: 'available'
}, {
  status: 'none'
}, {
  status: 'available'
}, {
  status: ''
}, {
  status: 'none'
}]

var array = $.map(products, function(value, index) {
 

  if (value["status"] == "available") {
    return [value];
  }

});

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/dvwu75ja/

Try This one

```
var products = [{status:'available'},{status:'none'},{status:'available'},{status:''},{status:'none'}];
x = 0;
products.forEach(function(element) {

    if(element["status"] == "available"){
       //code here, x is just to represent what index you are in now
        console.log(x);
    }
    x++;
});
```

Hopes this help

Answer (score 1):

```js
var products = [{status:'available'},{status:'none'},{status:'available'},{status:''},{status:'none'}];
for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
if(products[i].status == products[0].status){
 console.log(this.products[i]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  **ES5** most broswer support this one:

```
products.filter(function(product){return product.status === 'available'})
```

Using  **ES6** works too but not all browser support ES6 yet:

```
products.filter(product => product.status === 'available')
```